# How do I change the default image of an embedded YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

You can see on my website, i have placed a DIV over the youtube videos:

http://keywordresearcher.org/

But when i click the DIV, the video doesn't start.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've placed an element over the one that you want to click. So a click on that element, does not equal a click on the element you are trying to click.